# Counting a cardinality of a subset satisfying special property

Tags: list-manipulation, programming

Suppose that we have a set of 9 2-dimensional vectors $c$ by

```
m=3;
n=2;
c=Tuples[Range[m],n];
```

We want to define a subset $S$ of vectors in $c$ by the following:

$S=\{ (x,y)\in c~|~ x^2+2y^2=5\}$

Also, I want to count the cardinality of $S$.

How can I do this?

Comment: You can use `Select` and `Length` to do it.

Comment: ...or `Count[]`.

Comment: ...and of course there are no solutions in positive integers for this particular equation $x^2+2y^2=5$. For general equations of this type, please search for Cornacchia in this or other websites.

Comment: One could program the Cornacchia algorithm if need be, but for the lazy: `Reduce[x^2 + 2 y^2 == 5, {x, y}, Integers]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of brute force methods:

**Example:** $2x^2-3y^2=15$ -- there are 7 solutions up to $x,y=5\,000$.

*First method.*

```
(lim = 5*10^3;
 c = Tuples[Range[lim], 2];
 (sols = Pick[c, c^2 .{2, -3} - 15, 0])) // Timing
```

> ```
> {2.058927,
>   {{3, 1}, {9, 7}, {21, 17}, {87, 71}, {207, 169}, {861, 703}, {2049, 1673}}}
> ```

```
Length[sols]
```

> ```
> 7
> ```

Much faster than `Select`:

```
(c = Tuples[Range[lim], 2];
 Select[c, 2 #[[1]]^2 - 3 #[[2]]^2 == 15 &]) // Timing
```

> ```
> {103.844565,
>   {{3, 1}, {9, 7}, {21, 17}, {87, 71}, {207, 169}, {861, 703}, {2049, 1673}}}
> ```

*Second method.*

This one iterates through nesting.  There's an iterator `iterP` for when the coefficients have the same sign and one `iterN` for when they have opposite signs.  When they have opposite signs the number of solutions can be infinite, so there is a limit `n` on the number of iterations.  This is both much faster and uses much less memory.

```
iterN[{x_, y_, a_, b_, eqn_}] := Switch[Sign[eqn],
   -1, {x + 1, y, a, b, eqn + a (2 x + 1)},
   1, {x, y + 1, a, b, eqn + b (2 y + 1)},
   _, Sow[{x, y}]; {x + 1, y, a, b, eqn + a (2 x + 1)}];
iterP[{x_, y_, a_, b_, eqn_}] := Switch[Sign[eqn],
   1, {x - 1, y, a, b, eqn - a (2 x - 1)},
   -1, {x, y + 1, a, b, eqn + b (2 y + 1)},
   _, Sow[{x, y}]; {x - 1, y, a, b, eqn - a (2 x - 1)}];
solveSq[a_Integer, b_Integer, c_Integer, n_Integer] := Reap[If[a b > 0,
   NestWhileList[
    iterP,
    {Ceiling[Sqrt[Abs[c/a]]], 0, Sign[a] a, Sign[a] b, Sign[a] c + a Ceiling[Sqrt[Abs[c/a]]]^2},
    First[#] > 0 &, 1, n],
   Nest[
    iterN,
    {0, 0, Sign[a] a, Sign[a] b, Sign[a] c},
    n]]]
```

Same example:

```
solveSq[2, -3, -15, 100000] // Timing
```

> ```
> {0.057761,
>   {{6606, 5394, 2, -3, -7251},
>   {{{3, 1}, {9, 7}, {21, 17}, {87, 71}, {207, 169}, {861, 703}, {2049, 1673}}}}}
> ```

These are the solutions up to $x \le 6606$, $y \le 5394$.

**Example:** $2x^2+3y^2=105\,074$.

First method:

```
(m = 5*10^3;
 c = Tuples[Range[lim], 2];
 Pick[c, c^2 .{2, 3} - 105074, 0]) // Timing
```

> ```
> {1.790960,
>   {{101, 168}, {229, 8}}}
> ```

Second method:

```
solveSq[2, 3, -105074, 100000][[-1]] // Timing
```

> ```
> {0.002724,
>   {{{229, 8}, {101, 168}}}}
> ```

Comment: Thanks @Michael E2, I hadn't come across `Pick` before. That's useful to know that it can be so much faster than `Select`

Comment: @JonathanShock Yes, if you can make the second list quickly, then `Pick` will be fast.  In this case it's the internal, vectorized arithmetic that is much faster than testing each case, which is what `Select` does.

Answer (score 0):

You can work this out from the comments to your question, but it's good also to have a full answer.

You can select elements of a list which fulfill a particular requirement using the following syntax as an example:

```
m = 3;
n = 2;
c = Tuples[Range[m], n]
Select[c, #[[1]]^2 + 2 #[[2]]^2 == 9 &]
```

The second argument in `Select` is your criterion and essentially it is a pure function which takes the first and second elements of every entry in your tuple and tests to see if they fulfill the test (in this case it is `==9`, as `==5` gives you nothing). You can then ask for the `Length[]` of this list.